# How to resolve Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import './foo/' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from ./foo/host/build.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Here is the sequence of errors I am getting.

First, I am in a Node.js/TypeScript project and had this in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs"
}
```

My ~200 file Node.js/TypeScript project worked fine so far as CommonJS (which I realize is probably out of date now). I compile with `tsc && tsc-alias` (TypeScript compiler and [tsc-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-alias) is for resolving path aliases) into the `./host` directory, with the file I'm running in `host/build.js`.

Then I do `import chalk from 'chalk'` in some file, after npm installing [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk), and get this error:

```
const chalk_1 = __importDefault(require("chalk"));
                                ^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/lancepollard/start/drumwork/deck/base.link/node_modules/chalk/source/index.js from /Users/lancepollard/start/drumwork/deck/base.link/host/builder/error.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /Users/lancepollard/start/drumwork/deck/base.link/host/builder/error.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

How do I resolve *that* error?

So I try resolving it by changing my `tsconfig.json` to be `ES6`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES6",
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "outDir": "host",
    "rootDir": "make",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "baseUrl": "./make",
    "paths": {
      "~": ["."]
    },
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "include": ["make"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

And add this to my `package.json`:

```
"type": "module"
```

That gives me this error:

```
$ node host/build
node:internal/process/esm_loader:108
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^
Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import '/Users/lancepollard/start/drumwork/deck/base.link/host/' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from /Users/lancepollard/start/drumwork/deck/base.link/host/build.js
Did you mean to import ../index.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:253:17)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:876:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1084:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:161:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:831:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:413:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT',
  url: 'file:///Users/lancepollard/start/drumwork/deck/base.link/host/'
}
```

The original source for `build.ts` (which gets compiled to `host/build.js`) is this:

```
import { api } from '~'

const link = api.findPath('@treesurf/wolf')
api.assertString(link)
const base = api.createBase()
api.setEnvironmentVariable(base, 'dock', 'javascript')
api.setEnvironmentVariable(base, 'site', 'test')
api.handle_deckCard(base, link)
```

Where `~` resolves to the base folder/index of the project.

How do I get `chalk` to compile for my project, either by updating to ES6 or by doing "dynamic imports"? I would prefer to use the latest, whether that is commonjs or ES6.

Comment: Have you tried to build without `tsc-alias` and with the latest typescript?

Comment: Without `tsc-alias` I get `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '~' imported from /Users/lancepollard/start/drumwork/deck/base.link/host/build.js`, and I am using the latest typescript.

Comment: I can fix it using the experimental loaders feature, `node --no-warnings --loader @esbuild-kit/esm-loader host/build`, but is there a better way?